# Intersect collections with condition? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the intersection between two collections if the items satisfy a condition.

Here is my code so far:

```
facebook_friends.select {|friend| @liked_by.select {|liked| liked.id == friend["id"]}}
```

`facebook_friends` is a hash with information of a user's facebook friends.
`@liked_by` is an array of `Struct.new("Friend", :facebook_id, :id)` of users who liked a movie.

I am trying to get the Facebook friends that also liked the movie, but that sentence is giving me all Facebook friends, or sometimes with the same parameters just empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) returns a list of all elements from the array for which the block returns true; if none do, then it returns an empty array. The problem with your implementation is that your outer block will *always* evaluate to true, because even an empty array counts as a "true" value in Ruby. So what you want to do is change your inner block to only return `true` if the match actually exists; using, e.g., [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) instead of `select` will do that:

```
facebook_friends.select {|friend| @liked_by.any? {|liked| liked.id == friend["id"]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification. This worked perfectly.